# MySQL find row with the same string consisting of multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i search in MySQL to find the rows that have the same Column values?

Example:

```
ID  Brand   PN  Model
1   Puma    X3  Z3
2   Puma    X3  Z3
3   Nike    x4  Z3
4   Nike    x4  Z3
5   Puma    x3  Z3
6   Nike    x3  Z3
7   Puma    x4  Z3
8   Nike    x4  Z3
```

Here I want to know which rows (or here IDs) have the same "Brand-PN-Model" value

Here´s what I want to see in the end:

```
ID  Brand   PN  Model
1   Puma    X3  Z3
2   Puma    X3  Z3
5   Puma    x3  Z3
3   Nike    x4  Z3
4   Nike    x4  Z3
8   Nike    x4  Z3
```

Comment: Please edit your query and show the output that you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run this:

```
SELECT
    Brand,PN,Model,count(*) as Records
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    Brand,PN,Model
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: COUNT(*) doesn't need to be part of the select

Comment: this helped me the most and answered my needs even if not exactly, thank you alot

Answer (score 2):

You can collect the ids in one line using `group_concat()`:

```
select brand, pn, model, group_concat(id) as ids
from t
group by brand, pn, model;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select * from table Order by Brand;

Select * from table Group by Brand;

Either of the above would do it, you can also specify the exact attributes you want returned rather than * (all).